# Django DetailView update on one page not working - NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, detailview

I have a problem with update of my DetailView, so once i try to submit the updated values I am receiving an error NoReverseMatch at /task/164/. Could you please give me a hint what is wrong?

Thx!

urls:

```
path('excel_upload', ex_views.ExcelUploadView.as_view(), name='excel-upload'),
path('user_list', ex_views.UsersListView.as_view(), name = "user-list"),
path('excel_table', ex_views.ExcelTableView.as_view(), name = "excel-table"),
path("task/add", ex_views.TaskAddView.as_view(), name="task-add"),
path("task/<int:pk>/", ex_views.TaskDetailView.as_view(), name="task-detail"),
```

forms.py

```
class AddEditTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Task
    exclude = ['created_by']
    widgets = {
        "due_date": forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
        "completed_date": forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        "name":forms.TextInput(),
        "note": forms.Textarea(),
    }
```

views.py

```
class TaskDetailView(DetailView):
model = Task
template_name = "hana/task_detail.html"

# Add POST method
def post(self, request, pk):
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)
    form = AddEditTaskForm(request.POST, instance=task)
    if "add_edit_task" in request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "The task has been edited.")
            return redirect('excel-table')
    return render(request, 'hana/task_detail.html', {'form': form})
```

error:

NoReverseMatch at /task/164/
Reverse for 'task-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['task\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/task/164/
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'task-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['task\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']
Exception Location: /home/lukasz/envtest2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677

template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'task-detail' object.id %}" role="form" class="d-inline">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div style="display:inline;">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="submit" name="toggle_done">
                            {% if task.completed %} Mark Not Done {% else %} Mark Done {% endif %}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href={% url 'task-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: I forgot to present my submit button in template:   <p>
      <input type="submit" name="add_edit_task" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </p>

Comment: The error is in your `task_detail.html`. Please edit your question and post the source for that template.

Comment: I have added the part which is for sure problematic. There are 2 btns which are trigerring additional functions and i am passing there an object.id. Once I made first action empty, the problem was with the second i.e. task-delete btn. So how can I keep those btns in my template and don't have noreverse match error?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by mixing class based and function based views. Your function based `post` view uses the same template as your class based `TaskDetailView`, but since it doesn't have the same "magic" inherited from `DetailView`, there is no `object` passed in the context dictionary (you only pass `form`).

The proper fix would be to stick to the same view architecture when possible, but a trivial fix would be:

```
return render(request, 'hana/task_detail.html', {'form': form, 'object': task})
```

Comment: Hi Selcuk, many thanks for your hint. Firstly I did the easy fix with adding object to context and it he;ped in the way that I don't see the error but the adjusted data are not stored in the database. I would try to rebuild it into generic Class Views and get context object. Hoped it will help/.. BR Lukasz